# Getting a substring by index of a character in xpath for Camel

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-camel, saxon

I am using Camel and trying to set some headers based off an xml file.  The issue is that I need to set 2 headers which are combined into a single attribute in the xml and seperated by a colon ':'.

Here is the xml line:

```
<Alarm AlarmID="CC4567:180" DeviceID="CC0000:10.254.0.146" TimeStamp="2016-01-31 18:51:29.488">
```

I need to separate out the two parts of the AlarmID.  I know I can use the following:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="firstPart">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">substring(/ticket/alarmId,1,6)</xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
```

But the issue is that that the first part isn't actually limited to 6 characters.  I've tried the following but I get an error:

```
substring(/ticket/alarmId, 1, indexOf(':')-1)
```

error:
camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath: substring(/ticket/alarmId, indexOf(':')). Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unknown system function indexOf()

So my question is is there another way to do this since it seems camel doesn't support indexOf().  The goal being that I could have 2 headers, firstPart=CC4567 and secondPart=180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using saxon and <strike>it does not support</strike> it does not contain a function called indexOf. You need to use a valid xPath function to get what you want done. Try using the tokenize() function in xPath 2.0 that should allow you to split the string at ":".

Comment: Correct I am using saxon, so I'll look into tokenize().  Any chance this is a simple thing you could give an example of for my case?

Comment: Check the tokenize test cases in https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-saxon/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/builder/saxon/XPathTest.java. BTW, if this has been helpful, please consider upvoting my answer or comments. Would be helpful!

Comment: Your phrasing suggests that there is a defined function indexOf, and saxon is somehow deficient in not supporting it. Actually, there is no such function. If there were such a function, and if it were to do something similar to the Java and Javascript functions of the same name, it would need two arguments.

Comment: @MichaelKay my mistake. I was actually under the assumption that was the case. I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems IndexOf is not a defined function but substring-before() and `substring-after()` are, which work perfectly for my situation:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="firstPart">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">substring-before(/ticket/alarmId, ':')</xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
<camel:setHeader headerName="secondPart">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">substring-after(/ticket/alarmId, ':')</xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
```

This is also possible with Tokenizer as was suggested in another answer, using that would look like this:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="firstPart">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">tokenize(/ticket/alarmId,':')[1]</xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
<camel:setHeader headerName="secondPart">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">tokenize(/ticket/alarmId,':')[2]</xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
```

I went with the former option as I think it has better readability

Comment: You can also use `substring-before(/ticket/alarmId, ':')` and `substring-after(/ticket/alarmId, ':')`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay, that's much prettier readable, will update my answer with that